# How to use onTap and Draggable together in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need a widget to receive the `onTap` event and is draggable.

```
child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: _setVisibleSelect(),
    child: Draggable<Color>(
      data: Color(0x000000ff),
      child: Image.asset('assets/photo.png', color: Colors.yellow, width: 60, height: 60,),
      feedback: Image.asset('assets/photo.png', color: Colors.yellow, width: 60, height: 60,),
      childWhenDragging: Container(),
      ),
```

I can see `_setVisibleSelect()` doesn't work when `onTap` but Dragging.
How can I use two event together?

Comment: If you just want to check if it was tapped or not. You can wrap the Draggable with a InkWell widget instead of GestureDetector. That seems to be working fine.

Comment: It works with GestureDetector. What is your flutter version?

Comment: use flutter v1.16.0